# Scala fast text file read and upload to memory

Tags: file, scala, io, scalaz, scalaz-stream

In Scala, for reading a text file and uploading it into an array, a common approach is

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines.toArray
```

Especially for very large files, is there a faster approach perhaps by reading blocks of bytes into memory first and then splitting them by new line characters ? (See [Read entire file in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1284423/3189923) for commonly used approaches.)

Many Thanks.

Comment: Note that `Source` uses `BufferedSource`, which in turn uses Java's `BufferedReader`. So it already reads blocks of data into memory - it doesn't read byte-by-byte.

Comment: @DNA many thanks for the observation, wondering if there are (even) faster approaches, perhaps with java.nio ...

Comment: please, define *very large files* and what you're going to do with that data (after splitting it in lines)

Comment: @om-nom-nom numerical arrays 20.000 x 500 ~ 200MB

Comment: Next, obvious question is: how fast is your current approach and how fast would be *fast enough*?

Comment: @patryk-wiek faster than the version above, in the same machine for the same (very large) input file; likely for small files the version above if the fastest due to possible overhead in more sophisticated approaches...

Comment: `fromFile()` has an overloaded form that takes a bufferSize arg. Have you tried increasing that > 2048?

Comment: Quick approach, you could change the buffer size as @n0741337 says. If that is not enough, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5854889/54256 and http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly and use the code there to create something similar in Scala. Then, please, report back :D

Comment: I attempted a solution to this with NIO's `MappedByteBuffer` and it runs considerably slower, spending 3/4 of its time converting `Byte` arrays to `String`s. `Source` already makes efficient use of the old `java.io` classes, I suspect that there aren't any considerably faster solutions.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your current code (VisualVM's Sampler is pretty good for this kind of thing), to see what it's spending most of its time doing? Once you know that, you know what you need to target for optimisation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The performance problem has nothing to do with the way the data is read. It is already buffered. Nothing happens until you actually iterate through the lines:

```
// measures time taken by enclosed code
def timed[A](block: => A) = {
  val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis
  val result = block
  println("took " + (System.currentTimeMillis - t0) + "ms")
  result
}

val source = timed(scala.io.Source.fromFile("test.txt")) // 200mb, 500 lines
// took 0ms

val lines = timed(source.getLines)
// took 0ms

timed(lines.next) // read first line
// took 1ms

// ... reset source ...

var x = 0
timed(lines.foreach(ln => x += ln.length)) // "use" every line
// took 421ms

// ... reset source ...

timed(lines.toArray)
// took 915ms
```

Considering a read-speed of 500mb per second for my hard drive, the optimum time would be at 400ms for the 200mb, which means that there is no room for improvements other than not converting the iterator to an array.

Depending on your application you could consider using the iterator directly instead of an Array. Because working with such a huge array in memory will definitely be a performance issue anyway.

---

**Edit**:  From your comments I assume, that you want to further transform the array (Maybe split the lines into columns as you said you are reading a numeric array). In that case I recommend to do the transformation while reading. For example:

```
source.getLines.map(_.split(",").map(_.trim.toInt)).toArray
```

is considerably faster than

```
source.getLines.toArray.map(_.split(",").map(_.trim.toInt))
```

(For me it is 1.9s instead of 2.5s)
because you don't transform an entire giant array into another but just each line individually, ending up in one single array (Uses only half the heap space). Also since reading the file is a bottleneck, transforming while reading has the benefit that it results in better CPU utilization.