# How to read in a text file, line by line, and fill an object array with the information?

Tags: java

Figured it out...
I can't believer it took me that long just to get this:

```
        int id = inputFile.nextInt();
        String title = inputFile.next();
        String isbn = inputFile.next();
        String author = inputFile.next();
        String category = inputFile.next();
        char catagories = category.charAt(0);
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for getting your homework done... :-/

Comment: I understand that. I was hoping to be push in the right direction.
And @zvzdhk, I am not sure if I am doing the Book readInBooks = new Book.... correctly.

Comment: What happens when you run your program? Does it work? If not, what are you expecting it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Consider reading each line in one at a time with `inputFile.nextLine()`, then consider splitting the String returned with String's `split(" ")` method and using the array tokens returned in your constructor parameters.

Comment: why do people keep asking the same questions - here's a read line by line question for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800361/quickest-way-to-read-text-file-line-by-line-in-java

Comment: @JB Nizet it does not work. I am expecting it to do what I put in the description at the very, very end. And it crashes. "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)"

Comment: @radai: I don't think that your link will help the original poster out much. Yes the titles are similar, but the problems are different. His main problem is translating the data held by each row of Strings in the file into an object.

Comment: @trama: think of what happens when you call `nextLine()` when all you want is a single token on the line and when each row of data holds multiple tokens, each a component of the Book's information. You should logically be able to figure out what you're doing wrong here. This is more a matter of simply thinking through the problem, which you're not doing.

Answer (score 1):

The input is

```
96385 This_Book 0998706482 Smith Non-Fiction
```

But you're reading it using

```
 new Book(inputFile.nextInt(), inputFile.nextLine(), inputFile.nextLine(), inputFile.nextLine(), inputFile.nextLine())
```

So you're reading an int, then a whole line, then a whole line, then a whole line, then a whole line.

Use `next()` instead of `nextLine()`, since you want the next token, and not the next line.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it asks me to change the the Book constructor to (int, String, String, String, String). I need the last one to be a char.

Comment: @trama: You can easily extract a char from a String using one of String's methods, `charAt(...)`. 1+ to the correct answer.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. The last argument is *already* a String, since you're passing `input.nextLine()` which is a String. If you want to pass a char, then transform the last token into a char.