# Massive multiprogramming and read-only file access

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to create a dictionary-based tagger running on a Hadoop cluster using Pig. Basically, what it does, is for each document (quite large text documents, up to a few MBs) to run each word in each sentence against the dictionary to read the corresponding value.

There will be up to a few hundred java programs (not threads) running in parallel, using the dictionary file in read-only mode. The idea is to load the dictionary from text and create a `Map` to query against it.

> **Question: what should I be prepared for?** Is it even remotely logic to want to read a file in a multiprogramming environment or should I first copy the (relatively small) file for each instance of the program? Is a `BufferedReader` something I should use while reading the file?

There is very little structured documentation on multiprogramming (compared to multithreading) so I am a bit afraid of running against a wall by doing so.

*Note: you are only allowed to answer that my way of thinking is totally wrong if you provide me with a better way ;-)*

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5800450/2071828) might be relevant to you.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something more real-time than Hadoop...

Comment: Note sure if answers your question but We had couple of similar cases. One in which we had multiple mappers in hadoop traverse a large binary tree (fixed). We did this by using Memory mapping binary tree. Other use case was to analyze domain names against a dictionary. Here we used lucene index which shared by multiple mappers by using MMAPDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is fine. You should load your dictionary from the [`DistributedCache`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache) to memory, and do the checks with the memory-loaded dictionary (e.g., a `HashMap`).