# difference between Scanner & BufferReader

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scanner vs. BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader)

what is the difference between using the statements shown below:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = input.nextInt();
```

and

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);
int number = input.readLine();
```

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: this is wrong: `int number = input.readLine()`

Comment: what is the correction !! should it be String instead of int.

Comment: You should have tried your code in an IDE before posting it here. It' doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

suppose in the consol, you entered

```
10 20
```

and then press **ENTER** key

The first case will return 10 but the second case will not compile, because readLine() returns **String** not **int**.

In case if you try to parse that returned **String** to **int**, then also it gives **NumberFormatException**, as it reads the complete line, which contains two numbers along with a **WHITE SPACE**

Answer (score 1):

The first compiles, the second not.

A scanner will parse the input to a datatype, the BufferedReader will give the data line by line as it is.