# Efficiency while reading a txt file to an array

Tags: java, arrays, filereader, performance

I have written a script in which I read in *.txt* files to `arrays`. It works perfectly but I'm curious if there is a more efficient way of reading the *.txt* files in.
I have this:

```
try {
    String line;
    filestart = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\path\\file.txt));
    for (line = filestart.readLine(); line !=null; line = filestart.readLine()) {
        array.add (line);  
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there a function that combines `BufferedReader` and `FileReader`?

How would `Scanner` compare with what I have?

Comment: [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks. That's useful to know.

Comment: Seems efficient enough. For less code, look at Google Guava's `Files#readLines`.

Comment: In java 7 java.nio.files.Files#readAllLines, but actually does the same thing as you already do

Comment: And I just now realized my use of "a" instead of "of."  Whoops.

Comment: Whilst that is true, I can't see where anyone used it. Except here.

Comment: @SeanKenny - It is in the question's title: "Efficiency whilst reading a txt file to an array"

Comment: Sorry, yeah. Don't even know the title to my own question. Great work.