# Is using java.util.Scanner efficient just to read a Stream line-by-line?

Tags: java, io

It is rather compact to just create a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and then call the [nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) on it. But is it as efficient as using BufferedReader? (and what's the case in 1.6?)

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "efficient", not "effective".

Comment: pihentagy you don't use `BufferedInputStream` to read text...  One difference between `Scanner` and `BufferedReader` is whether the newline character(s) are included.  `Scanner.nextLine()` includes the newline character(s), while `BufferedReader.readLine()` does not.

Comment: @Michael: you are wrong. In `nextLine`'s javadoc: `This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end.`

Comment: @pihentagy Oops, sorry I misread it.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedReader` is more efficient if all you want to do is read each line, as that is all it does. 
`Scanner` also parses the line, and has a smaller buffer (though this is rarely an issue), so is, at least theoretically, less efficient but a lot easier to use than setting up your own parsing if all you want is simple stuff (so `nextDouble()`, `nextInt()` etc. are easier with a `Scanner`, but line-by-line reading is probably better done with a `BufferedReader`)

Also, google is your friend [Scanner vs. BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader)

Comment: Nice SO question you found.  Important points from the answers: (1) `Scanner` can do everything `BufferedReader` can, and then some.  (2) `Scanner` has a slightly smaller buffer than `BufferedReader` (1KB vs 8KB). (3) `BufferedReader` is synchronized, and `Scanner` is not.