# Taking inputs with BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java, input

I have a bit of an annoying case here; wherein I am not able to take the input properly. I have always taken input via `Scanner`, and am not used to the `BufferedReader`.

---

**INPUT FORMAT**

---

```
First line contains T, which is an integer representing the number of test cases.
T cases follow. Each case consists of two lines.

First line has the string S. 
The second line contains two integers M, P separated by a space.
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

```
Input:
2
AbcDef
1 2
abcabc
1 1
```

---

**My code so far:**

---

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int T= Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());

    for(int i=0;i<T;i++) {
        String s= inp.readLine();
        int[] m= new int[2];
        m[0]=inp.read();
        m[1]=inp.read();

        // Checking whether I am taking the inputs correctly
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(m[0]);
        System.out.println(m[1]);
    }
}
```

---

When inputting to the above example shown, I get the following output:

```
AbcDef
9
49
2
9
97
```

Comment: your m[0]=inp.read(); is reading a byte or something. do a readline into a string and split it to get the two fields, then parse them to ints.

Comment: `inp.read()` will read a single character(16 bit) not byte(8 bit).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`BufferedReader#read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) reads  single character[0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff)] from the stream, so it is not possible to read single integer from stream.

```
            String s= inp.readLine();
            int[] m= new int[2];
            String[] s1 = inp.readLine().split(" ");
            m[0]=Integer.parseInt(s1[0]);
            m[1]=Integer.parseInt(s1[1]);

            // Checking whether I am taking the inputs correctly
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println(m[0]);
            System.out.println(m[1]);
```

You can check also [Scanner vs. BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader).

Answer (score 1):

You can't read individual integers in a single line separately using `BufferedReader` as you do using `Scanner`class.
 Although, you can do something like this in regard to your query :

```
import java.io.*;
class Test
{
   public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
       {
         String str=br.readLine();
         String num[]=br.readLine().split(" ");
         int num1=Integer.parseInt(num[0]);
         int num2=Integer.parseInt(num[1]);
         //rest of your code
       }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.