# Difference between BufferedReader readLine() and Scanner nextInt()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I was reading on the difference between Scanner and BufferedReader on stackoverflow.

In one of the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14292918

It was mentioned that there is a difference in

```
Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())
```

and

```
scanner.nextInt();
```

Which is how new lines are handled.

Can someone expand on this, preferrably with an example ?

Comment: `Scanner.nextInt()` does not eat up the new line character at the end of the line so the cursor is still on the same line and doesn't move to the next line. It will only get the next `Integer`.  `BufferedReader.readLine()` will read the entire line.

Comment: Is there a difference between `Scanner.readLine()` and `br.readLine()`?

Answer (score 4):

`Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())`  <-- reads a complete line then convert it to integer

`scanner.nextInt();`  <-- reads the next token within the input then tries to convert it to integer

**NOTE:**

Both may `throw Exception` if the `String` they find is **NOT** convertible to `Integer`

Comment: thanks...it was as simple as that...I was thinking it was something more complicated..