# Loop a search for a string using BufferedReaders?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm using two BufferedReaders, one to read a document, and another one to get the input of the String to search from user, heeding the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577688/search-a-file-for-a-string-and-return-that-string-if-found). Here's the code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Ejercicio6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Character answer = 'S'; 
        boolean exit = false;
        String name;
        String line;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        boolean found = false;

        File file = new File ("/test/Ejercicio6/nombres.txt");

        try {

            do{

                exit = false;
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println("Search a name, I'll tell you if it's found:");
                name = userInput.readLine();
                while ((line = readFile.readLine()) != null && found == false){
                    if(line.equals(name)) {
                        found = true;
                    }else
                        found = false;
                }

                if (found == true)
                    System.out.println("I have found the name " +name+ " in the file " +file.getName());
                if (found == false)
                        System.out.println("Can't find the name");
                fis.getChannel().position(0);
                fileRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

                System.out.println("Do you want to try again? (Y/N)");
                answer = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                if (answer =='S'){

                    exit = false;
                }else

                    exit = true;
                fileRead.close();
            }while (exit == false);

//      }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

There are 3 names on the document, but I always get the "name found" print, regardless of the input matching or not. I'm trying to figure out how does the getChannel() and the buffer clearing, as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421653/reset-buffer-with-bufferedreader-in-java), but I'm having lots of trouble. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unset your flag found to false again after you're printing for matched or unmatched name.
Just add

`found = false;`

before

`fis.getChannel().position(0);`

Comment: Simple solution, as I expected. Many thanks, worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (line.equals(name)) {
    found = true;
} else
    found = false;
```

can simplied:

```
found = line.equals(name);
```

Just move `boolean found = false;` right before while loop

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Character answer;
        boolean exit;
        String name;
        String line;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        try {
            do {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println("Search a name, I'll tell you if it's found:");
                name = userInput.readLine();
                boolean found = false;
                while ((line = readFile.readLine()) != null && found == false) {
                    found = line.equals(name);
                }
                if (found == true)
                    System.out.println("I have found the name " + name + " in the file " + file.getName());
                if (found == false)
                    System.out.println("Can't find the name");
                fis.getChannel().position(0);
                BufferedReader fileRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                System.out.println("Do you want to try again? (Y/N)");
                answer = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                exit = answer != 'S';
                fileRead.close();
            } while (exit == false);
//      }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```