# Java OutOfMemoryError in reading a large text file

Tags: java, file-io, out-of-memory, arrays

I'm new to Java and working on reading very large files, need some help to understand the problem and solve it. We have got some legacy code which have to be optimized to make it run properly.The file size can vary from 10mb to 10gb only. only trouble start when file starting beyond 800mb size.

```
InputStream inFileReader = channelSFtp.get(path); // file reading from ssh.
byte[] localbuffer = new byte[2048];
ByteArrayOutputStream bArrStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int i = 0;
while (-1 != (i = inFileReader.read(buffer))) {
bArrStream.write(localbuffer, 0, i);
}

byte[] data = bArrStream.toByteArray();
inFileReader.close();
bos.close();
```

We are getting the error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: In the sample code you mentioned, you are simply loading the entire file in `ByteArrayOutputStream`. What is the use case ? Do really need the entire file data in a `byte[]` ?

Comment: Can you let me know which JDK version you are planning to use , i have different solution for JDK 8 and JDK7 or lesser.

Comment: @Luffy does it make sense to answer this question without knowing **why** so much data is read into memory?

Comment: You should increase heap size as stated in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java But remember that the Java runtime and you code take some space as well so add some buffer to the desired maximum.

Comment: What if the input files are unbounded in size and not within your control?

Comment: Not controlling the file size is basically always the case when you release your software but most of the time, you can ballpark file sizes that will be fed to your program. When you cannot guess, what I've seen in other java commercial app is a piece of documentation that explains how to configure the java runtime max heap parameter to fit your needs. The insallation default is usually set to an amount of heap covering 95% of cases.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to use **java.nio.MappedByteBuffer**.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html

You can map a file's content onto memory without copying it manually. High-level Operating Systems offer memory-mapping and Java has API to utilize the feature.

If my understanding is correct, memory-mapping does not load a file's entire content onto memory (meaning "loaded and unloaded partially as necessary"), so I guess a 10GB file won't eat up your memory.

Answer (score 14):

Even though you can increase the JVM memory limit, it is needless and allocating a huge memory like 10GB to process a file sounds overkill and resource intensive.

Currently you are using a "ByteArrayOutputStream" which keeps an internal memory to keep the data. This line in your code keeps appending the last read 2KB file chunk to the end of this buffer:

```
bArrStream.write(localbuffer, 0, i);
```

bArrStream keeps growing and eventually you run out of memory.

Instead you should reorganize your algorithm and process the file in a streaming way:

```
InputStream inFileReader = channelSFtp.get(path); // file reading from ssh.
byte[] localbuffer = new byte[2048];

int i = 0;
while (-1 != (i = inFileReader.read(buffer))) {
    //Deal with the current read 2KB file chunk here
}

inFileReader.close();
```

Answer (score 7):

The Java virtual machine (JVM) runs with a fixed upper memory limit, which you can modify thus:

```
java -Xmx1024m ....
```

e.g. the above option (-Xmx...) sets the limit to 1024 megabytes. You can amend as necessary (within limits of your machine, OS etc.) Note that this is different from traditional applications which would allocate more and more memory from the OS upon demand.

However a better solution is to rework your application such that you don't need to load the *whole* file into memory at one go. That way you don't have to tune your JVM, and you don't impose a huge memory footprint.

Answer (score 5):

You can't read 10GB Textfile in memory. You have to read X MB first, do something with it and than read the next X MB.

Comment: If he has 10Gb and a 64bit JVM he *can* do this. He probably shouldn't, though.

Comment: @Brian No he can't. Even under 64bit there is only a limited size of elements in an array possible.

Comment: Depends on what kind of data this is @A.P.S

Comment: @user2717498 - I'm simply contradicting your assertion that you can't load a 10Gb file in memory. You could do it by storing arrays of lines, for example

Answer (score 4):

The problem is inherent in what you're doing. Reading entire files into memory is always and everywhere a bad idea. You're really not going to be able to read a 10GB file into memory with current technology unless you have some pretty startling hardware. Find a way to process them line by line, record by record, chunk by chunk, ...

Comment: "Reading entire files into memory is always and everywhere a bad idea" ? Tell that to my editor! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Is it mandatory to get entire `ByteArray()` of output stream?

```
byte[] data = bArrStream.toByteArray();
```

Best approach is read line by line & write it line by line. You can use `BufferedReader` or `Scanner` to read large files as below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileReadExample {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File fileObj = new File(args[0]);

    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        // BufferedReader object for reading the file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileObj)); 
        // Reading each line of file using BufferedReader class
        String str;
        while ( (str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }catch(Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken for BufferedReader:"+(t2-t1));

    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try (
        // Scanner object for reading the file
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileObj);) {
        // Reading each line of file using Scanner class
        while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
            String strLine = scnr.nextLine();
            // print data on console
            System.out.println(strLine);
        }
    }
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken for scanner:"+(t2-t1));

  }
}
```

You can replace `System.out` with your `ByteArrayOutputStream` in above example.

Please have a look at below article for more details: [Read Large File](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/corejava/files/java-read-large-file-efficiently.html)

Have a look at related SE question:

[Scanner vs. BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader)

Answer (score 3):

`ByteArrayOutputStream` writes to an in-memory buffer. If this is really how you want it to work, then you have to size the JVM heap after the maximum possible size of the input. Also, if possible, you may check the input size before even start processing to save time and resources.

The alternative approach is a streaming solution, where the amount of memory used at runtime is known (maybe configurable but still known before the program starts), but if it's feasible or not depends entirely on you application's domain (because you can't use an in-memory buffer anymore) and maybe the architecture of the rest of your code if you can't/don't want to change it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a large buffer read size may be 10 mb and then check.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are reading large txt file and the data is set  line by line  , use line by line reading approach. As I know you can read up to 6GB may be more.

...

```
// Open the file
 FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

  String strLine;

 //Read File Line By Line
 while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Print the content on the console
  System.out.println (strLine);
 }

 //Close the input stream
 br.close();
```

[Refrence for the code fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

Answer (score 3):

Read the file iteratively linewise. This would significantly reduce memory consumption. Alternately you may use

> FileUtils.lineIterator(theFile, "UTF-8");

provided by Apache Commons IO.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
Scanner sc = null;
try {
inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    // System.out.println(line);
}
// note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
if (sc.ioException() != null) {
    throw sc.ioException();
}
} finally {
if (inputStream != null) {
    inputStream.close();
}
if (sc != null) {
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Run Java with the command-line option -Xmx, which sets the maximum size of the heap.

[See here for details..](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABHDABI)

Comment: This isn't a permanent fix. What if you don't know how large the input files can be?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer,

without doing anything, you can push the current limit by a factor of 1.5. It means that, if you are able to process 800MB, you can process 1200 MB. It also means that if by some trick with `java -Xm ....` you can move to a point where your current code can process 7GB, your problem is solved, because the 1.5 factor will take you to 10.5GB, assuming you have that space available on your system and that JVM can get it.

Long answer:

The error is pretty self-descriptive. You hit the practical memory limit on your configuration. There is a lot of speculating about the limit that you can have with JVM, I do not know enough about that, since I can not find any official information. However, you will somehow be limited by constraints like the available swap, the kernel address space usage, the memory fragmentation, etc.

What is happening now is that `ByteArrayOutputStream` objects are created with a default buffer of size 32 if you do not supply any size (this is your case). Whenever you call the `write` method on the object, there is an internal machinery that is started. The [openjdk implementation release 7u40-b43](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.java?av=f) that seems to match perfectly with the output of your error, uses an internal method `ensureCapacity` to check that the buffer has enough room to put the bytes you want to write. If there is not enough room, another internal method `grow` is called to grow the size of the buffer. The method `grow` defines the appropriate size and calls the method `copyOf` from the class `Arrays` to do the job.
The appropriate size of the buffer is the maximum between the current size and the size riquired to hold all the content (the present content and the new content to be write).
The method `copyOf` from the class `Arrays` ([follow the link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.copyOf%28byte[]%2Cint%29)) allocates the space for the new buffer, copy the content of the old buffer to the new one and return it to `grow`.

Your problem occurs at the allocation of the space for the new buffer, After some `write`, you got to a point where the available memory is exhausted: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

If we look into details, you are reading by chunks of 2048. So

- your first write to the grows the size of the buffer from 32 to 2048
- your second call will double it to 2*2048
- your third call will take it to 2^2*2048, you have to time to write two more times before the need of allocating.
- then 2^3*2048, you will have the time for 4 mores writes before allocating again.
- at some point, your buffer will be of size 2^18*2048 which is 2^19*1024 or 2^9*2^20 (512 MB)
- then 2^19*2048 which is 1024 MB or 1 GB

Something that is unclear in your description is that you can somehow read up to 800MB, but can no go beyond. You have to explain that to me.

I expect that your limit be exactly a power of 2 (or close if we use power of 10 units somewere). In that regard, I expect you to start having trouble immediatly above one of these: 256MB, 512 MB, 1GB, 2GB, etc.

When you hit that limit, it does not mean that you are out of memory, it simply means that it is not possible to allocate another buffer of twice the size of the buffer you already have. This observation opens room for improvement in your work: find the maximum size of buffer that you can allocate and reserve it upfront by calling the appropriate constructor

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bArrStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(myMaxSize);
```

It has the advantage of reducing the overhead background memory allocation that happens under the hood to keep you happy. By doing this, you will be able to go to 1.5 the limit you have right now. This is simply because the last time the buffer was increased, it went from half the current size to the current size, and at some point you had both the current buffer and the old one together in memory. But you will not be able to go beyond 3 times the limit you are having now. The explanation is exactly the same.

That been said, I do not have any magic suggestion to solve the problem apart from process your data by chunks of given size, one chunk at a time. Another good approach will be to use the suggestion of Takahiko Kawasaki and use `MappedByteBuffer`. Keep in mind that in any case you will need at least 10 GB of physical memory or swap memory to be able to load a file of 10GB.

see

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it, I decided to put a second answer. I considered the advantages and disadvantages of putting this second answer, and the advantages are worth going for it. So here it is.

Most of the suggested considerations are forgetting a given fact: There is a builtin limit in the size of arrays (including `ByteArrayOutputStream`) that you can have in Java. And that limit is dictated by the bigest `int` value which is 2^31 - 1(little bit less than 2Giga). This means that you can only read a maximum of 2 GB (-1 byte) and put it in a single `ByteArrayOutputStream`. The limit might actually be smaller for array size if the VM wants more control.

My suggestion is to use an `ArrayList` of `byte[]` instead of a single `byte[]` holding the full content of the file. And also remove the non necessary step of putting in `ByteArrayOutputStream` before putting it in a final `data` array. Here is an example based on your original code:

```
InputStream inFileReader = channelSFtp.get(path); // file reading from ssh.

// good habits are good, define a buffer size
final int BUF_SIZE = (int)(Math.pow(2,30)); //1GB, let's not go close to the limit

byte[] localbuffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];

int i = 0;
while (-1 != (i = inFileReader.read(localbuffer))) {
    if(i<BUF_SIZE){
        data.add( Arrays.copyOf(localbuffer, i) )
        // No need to reallocate the reading buffer, we copied the data
    }else{
        data.add(localbuffer)
        // reallocate the reading buffer
        localbuffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE]
    }
}

inFileReader.close();
// Process your data, keep in mind that you have a list of buffers.
// So you need to loop over the list
```

Simply running your program should work fine on 64 bits system with enough physical memory or swap. Now if you want to speed it up to help the VM size correctly the heap at the beginning, run with the options `-Xms` and `-Xmx`. For example if you want a heap of 12GB to be able to handle 10GB file, use `java -Xms12288m -Xmx12288m YourApp`