# BufferedReader with FileReader uses a lot of RAM

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I use `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` on very big files (~100g).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file path"));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output file"));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // check if i need this line, and if i need it, i print it
    writer.write(line);
    writer.newLine();
}
writer.close();
reader.close();
```

When I run this on my files in the beginning it uses a low amount of memory but slowly the used memory grows (can easily use over than 50GB of RAM).

Why it's like that? And, can I fix it somehow?

Comment: What are you doing with the lines?

Comment: @JonSkeet i update my question. i take each line and split it by tabs (my files are tab-delimited), and check if i need this line, i print it with BufferedWriter to a output file.

Comment: So you're not *saving* it anywhere? With the code you've presented, I'd expect the garbage collector to handle it with no problems... unless you have huge *individual lines* in your files.

Comment: @JonSkeet im not saving the rows anywhere, i immediatly print the needed rows to another file

Comment: And you're not saving any *part* of it? It would help if you could provide a [mcve] here so we could try to reproduce it. (As well as a rough idea of what's in your files, so we can generate something similar.)

Comment: 50g of RAM? How much heap do you have configured there? And what exactly do you mean by "used memory"?

Comment: Take a heap dump and analyze it :)

Comment: Maybe your files just don't use line breaks?

Comment: This code does not leak memory. Clearly the problem is in the part of the code you haven't posted.

Comment: Don't edit answers/solution into your question, instead create an answer post. Then don't write "solved" into the title, accept the answer, which solved your issue, instead. And also explain how you used the `-Xmx` parameter. Maybe the passed value was set incorrectly.

Comment: Hi Idorini, have a look at this question for reading a large file. Add write logic to solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508836/java-outofmemoryerror-in-reading-a-large-text-file/31724120#31724120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that when i run java program on linux from command line with `-Xmx` parameter, for some reason it make my java program to need to alot of RAM.

From when i remove `-Xmx` parameter, the java program use low memory.

---

This was my old command:

```
java -Xmx350g -jar MyJar.jar
```

This is my new command:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Comment: I didn't knew it was even possible to allocate 350g to the JVM ... Also, maybe the garbage collector only starts after a certain % of the space is taken ?..

Comment: @Asoub I run it on strong server, so when you have 512g of RAM, it shouldnt be a problem to allocate 350g. And i think you may right about the garbage collector, but i dont really know.