# Json Obj to String to Bytes to ByteArrayInputStream throws OutOfMemory Error

Tags: java, arrays, out-of-memory, bytearrayinputstream

I have a JsonString that needs to be written in file to proceed with further processing. I've written the below code for file writing.

```
val json = "{}"  // sample Json.
val jsonString = new StringBuilder()

val formatjson = PrettyParams.nospace.copy(preserveOrder = true).pretty(json)
jsonString.append(formatjson)

val tmpFileIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(
  jsonString.toString().getBytes()
)
try {
  IOUtils.copyLarge(tmpFileIS, tmpBufferedOutputStream)
  tmpBufferedOutputStream.flush()
} catch {
  case e: Exception => {
    e.printStackTrace()
    throw e
  }
} finally {
  tmpFileIS.close()
}
```

I'm getting below OOM issue, exactly at the line of where I've written `jsonString.toString().getBytes()`

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)

It looks like the JSON content's been generated is over the heap memory and throwing an error.

I should not be increasing a heap memory this time nor allocate more heap memory all the time for this kind of rare instance.

So, do I need to split the JSON contents into pieces and write it a file?
Hope it could solve the issue and be memory efficient.
but does anyone have a better solution for reading a `String` byte to byte or `byte[]` to feed `ByteArrayInputStream`?

Comment: @cchantep Why did you remove the `scala` tag from a question about Scala code?

Comment: I guess you find the answer in this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508836/java-outofmemoryerror-in-reading-a-large-text-file

Comment: There is no need for the `StringBuilder` or the `ByteArrayInputStream` or `IOUtils.copyLarge()` here. Just write the original String directly to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to avoid `OutOfMemoryError` is to use streams directly when building large data structures. Your code copies the json twice. See whether you can pretty format the json directly to an `OutputStream` for the file, not via `String` + `byte[]`.

Alternatively since JDK11 you can use [Files.writeString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) which eliminates most of your code (- though this assumes you haven't got OOME already when creating the pretty formatted json). Change charset / open options to suit so that the file content has your preferred encoding:

```
Files.writeString(formatjson, path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
// or platform default encoding:
Files.writeString(formatjson, path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```