# Accepting input from keyboard using Scanner after calling method in imported class

Tags: methods, keyboard, java.util.scanner

I'm having great trouble with accepting input from the keyboard after transferring control to another method located in another class in my program. The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at com.group.work.fileReadWriter.WritetoFile(fileReadWriter.java:23)
    at com.group.work.highCipher.main(highCipher.java:32)
```

The following is my code in my main. I've not stripped it down so as to allow you to see the multiple ways I've tried before posting this question, up to the point where the problem exists.

```
package com.group.work;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
import fileDecrypter;
import fileEncrypter;
import fileReadWriter;
*/

public class highCipher {


public static void main(String[] args) {

fileReadWriter obj = new fileReadWriter();
int choice;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//fileEncrypter objd = null;

    System.out.println("What Would You Like To Do ? \n 1 - Write To File \n 2 - Read From File \n ?:");
    //String choic = scan.next();
    choice = scan.nextInt();
    //scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
    //choice = Integer.parseInt(choic);
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            obj.WritetoFile();
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {   
            obj.ReadfromFile();
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Value Entered");
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is the class containing the method that was called from `obj.WritetoFile()`

```
package com.group.work;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fileReadWriter {
    private String input = null;
    //String Fname[]=new String[2]; 
    //String Lname[]= new String[2];
    private Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void WritetoFile (){
    //  InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

    try{

        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("output.txt"));
    {
        System.out.println("please enter a full name");
        //input = in.readLine(); /* I will get errors here,
        //input = in.next();        here,
        input = in.nextLine();      here,
        /*
        for(int x=0; x<Fname.length; x++){
         Fname[x] = in.next();       and here. */

         Lname[x] = in.next();
         }

        */
    //for(int i =0;i<Fname.length;i++){
      //  String sc =" ";

        //output.println( Fname[i] +sc+ Lname[i] );
        output.println(input);
        }
        output.close();

        System.out.println ("File created successfully");

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    return;
    }
```

Note that, in reference to the Fname & Lname String array, I plan to remove it from the final build of the project. I plan to use the `String input` to accept and write things to the file.

Once more, the problem I face is accepting input from the keyboard in the line after prompting the user to enter a full name. The program skips over it, recording a null value, and causing the rest of my program to not work properly (clearly).

I understand that `nextLine()` does not wait for the user's input (http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090103175947AA5pyjq) , but returns everything before the newline character, but even with using BufferedReader to accept input instead, even after closing the Scanner from main, even after using different variable names, I can't seem to evade this problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
changes to make it work

comment out:
scan.close in main 

and uncomment:

input = in.readLine()
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main file
=====================
package simlpe;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
import fileDecrypter;
import fileEncrypter;
import fileReadWriter;
*/

public class simple {


public static void main(String[] args) {

fileReadWriter obj = new fileReadWriter();
int choice;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//fileEncrypter objd = null;

    System.out.println("What Would You Like To Do ? \n 1 - Write To File \n 2 - Read From File \n ?:");
    //String choic = scan.next();
    choice = scan.nextInt();
    //scan.nextLine();
  //  scan.close();
    //choice = Integer.parseInt(choic);
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            obj.WritetoFile();
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {   
          obj.ReadfromFile();
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Value Entered");
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
other file
============
package simlpe;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fileReadWriter {
    private String input = null;
    String Fname[]=new String[2]; 
    String Lname[]= new String[2];
    private Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void WritetoFile (){
      InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

    try{

        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("output.txt"));
    {
        System.out.println("please enter a full name");
        input = in.readLine();// I will get errors here,
        //input = in.next();      //  here,
      //  input = in.nextLine();     // here,

        for(int x=0; x<Fname.length; x++){
       //  Fname[x] = in.next();

       //  Lname[x] = in.next();
         }


    //for(int i =0;i<Fname.length;i++){
      //  String sc =" ";

        //output.println( Fname[i] +sc+ Lname[i] );
        output.println(input);
        }
        output.close();

        System.out.println ("File created successfully");

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    return;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Wow. Can you explain to me WHY and HOW this works?
Also, MUST I use `Scanner` to accept input from keyboard ? Is there no other way, apart from `BufferedReader` ?
I really like java, except for this very little part. I wish it was as easy as `cin >> variable`. Even `scanf("%d");` wasn't so bad. Sigh.

Comment: actually your question had its answer.scanner and buffered reader are 2 different methods to read input.to see differences between them           see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader  .so to answer your questions.1)no scanner neednt be used u can use buffered reader.2)scanner is another choice apart from buffered reader

Comment: and java is pretty easy as well a simple example                                                         System.out.println("enter name");                               Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);                                                    String s=scan.nextLine();

Comment: I Realize I had the answer. I didn't try mixing them together.. Dont know why it didn't work. But thanks anyway