# Code fails when multiple words inputed

Tags: java

:D I'm completly new to Java and now I'm doing basic examples(with Java 1.7 and Eclipse IDE)

I have tried the code below.It should take user inputs an them display them in the end.

```
package loop;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

    String name;
    System.out.print("What is yout name?: ");
    name = user_input.next();

    String quest;
    System.out.print("What is your quest?: ");
    quest = user_input.next();

    String color;
    System.out.print("What is your favourite color?: ");
    color = user_input.next();

    String sentence;
    sentence = "Your name is" + " " + name + " " + ",and your quest is" + " " + quest + " " + ",and your favourite color is" + " " + color;

    System.out.println(sentence);





    }

}
```

and everything thing works fine when I use only one word for input like here

```
What is yout name?: Marko
What is your quest?: seeking
What is your favourite color?: green
Your name is Marko ,and your quest is seeking ,and your favourite color is green
```

but everything fails with multiple words inputed:

```
What is yout name?: Marko Scekic
What is your quest?: What is your favourite color?: seeking blue
Your name is Marko ,and your quest is Scekic ,and your favourite color is seeking

What is yout name?: Marko
What is your quest?: seeking for Holy grail
What is your favourite color?: Your name is Marko ,and your quest is seeking ,and your favourite color is for
```

I tried everything that is in my power(I replaced print with println and reversed,tried changing the order of the questions etc..).

Comment: Then use `user_input.nextLine();` etc

Comment: @Reimeus Thanks,that defineatly worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what Reimeus said: `Scanner.next()` returns the next *token* from the scanner. Basically, it regards whitespace as a delimiter between tokens meaning that "Marko Scekic" is two different tokens: "Marko" being the first, and "Scekic" being the second.

You may be thinking of it like this: first the code does a System.out.println("What is your name?"); then asks the user for information using `next()` and then prints something else with `System.out.println()` so it seems that `next()` should give everything that was input between the two `println()` calls.

Unfortunately, the Scanner class doesn't know anything at all about whether System.out.println() has been called or not. From its point of view the following are exactly the same:

```
String name;
System.out.print("What is yout name?: ");
name = user_input.next();

String quest;
System.out.print("What is your quest?: ");
quest = user_input.next();
```

and

```
String name;
name = user_input.next();

String quest;
quest = user_input.next();
```

In other words, printing things using `System.out.println()` has no effect on what `next()` does.

So you need to either use something different than `Scanner`, or as Reimus said, use `nextLine()`, since this will return everything from the beginning of the line until the point that the user hits the enter key (which is a '\n' character).

Answer (score 2):

As Reimeus stated earlier you should use user_input.nextLine();

This will read the complete line, and will read everything until \n is found, which means a new line, in your case the user hits enter.

Answer (score 1):

You should better use a BufferedReader

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

to get input:

For example:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String name;
System.out.print("What is yout name?: ");
name = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Comment: How is `BufferedReader` better?

Comment: I read this and I think its better for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use scanner, you will need to use the `nextLine()` method from Scanner to get the whole line. It reads in the whole line including spaces. Now using the `next()` method only reads up until the first space then stops.

```
String name;
System.out.print("What is yout name?: ");
name = user_input.nextLine();
//etc...
```

[Link to java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)