# Advantage of using a Scanner object or BufferedReader object

Tags: java

I often keep making menu-driven programs for which  the User requires to enter his choice many times.

That's why , I wanna know-
**What edge does a 'Scanner' object provides over a 'BufferedReader' object or vice-versa?**

and **How to take mutliple inputs using a 'BufferedReader' object ?(without using loops)"

P.S.- I know can that characters(Parsed) in BufferedReader

Comment: I think that similar questions appeared on the website. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader

Comment: How about reading their documentation to see what both classes can and can't do? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: @Radek - I used to Research bar to find that but it didn't show that a similar question has been asked.

Comment: @user3253946 try Google: http://goo.gl/SFHfxg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this article 
 [here](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Java-1046/2009/2/Difference-Scanner-Method-Buffered.htm)

**BufferedReader**

- A BufferedReader is a simple class meant to efficiently read from the underling stream
- read() or readLine() could cause bytes to be read from the file, converted into characters, and then returned, which can be very inefficient
- Efficiency is improved appreciably if a Reader is warped in a BufferedReader.
- BufferedReader is synchronized, so read operations on a BufferedReader can safely be done from multiple threads

**Scanner**

- Scanner can do all that a BufferedReader can do and at the same level of efficiency
- Scanner can parse the underlying stream for primitive types and strings using regular expressions

I suggest to use BufferedReader because it throws the exception immediately

Comment: What does "IOException" means?

Comment: Simply  - Input Output Exceptions read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html