# While loop won't exit Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, exit

I'm entering a huge number and adding each line of numbers to the string "hold".
Once there's nothing left to read it should exit the while loop and turn the string to a BigInteger.

It will run through the loop till there is nothing left then nothing happens. It doesn't continue to BigInteger or go into the loop again. I've looked everywhere and can't figure out why it's stuck.

```
System.out.print("Enter the number you want looked at: ");
String hold = "";
String line = null;
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while ((line = read.readLine()) != null){
    hold = hold.concat(line);
}
BigInteger giantNumber = new BigInteger(hold);

System.out.print(giantNumber);
```

I want it to exit the loop without the user doing anything more then entering the number at the beginning.

It seems to get stuck because System.in is looking for more input and isn't receiving anything to compare in the while loop. I'm not sure what to do from there.

The number I'm entering is, if that helps:

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Comment: why you need `while` if you are reading single line  ?

Comment: have you debugged that piece of code. It's possible that while loop doesn't exit and continues forever

Comment: Do you run this in interactive mode?

Comment: @JigarJoshi the number is spread across several lines. 123 new line 456 etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: this code will read each line and wait for user to enter new line, if you want to terminate have a terminator code (exit, quit, stop..) or something to stop taking inputs and add that condition in while block

Comment: @CommuSoft I'm using Intellij in the debug menu if that's what you mean.

Comment: @BarbarianBunny: no, how are you providing input? Using the terminal or with I/O redirection.

Comment: If you want to quite by entering ENTER then probably you need to check for empty tring, not null

Comment: @JigarJoshi the whole number with the line breaks is entered at once so the user shouldn't also have to enter a terminator

Comment: what is the difference between single line input and the way you are describing

Comment: @CommuSoft oh sorry I'm new to programming so I'm not used to the terms. I'm just entering it where it says Console in Intellij.

Comment: @TonyVu I tried using while ((line = read.readLine()) != "") but that doesn't work. How would you suggest I check for an empty string?

Comment: @BarbarianBunny, !="" won't work. Use length() == 0.

Comment: @TonyVu I tried using while ((line = read.readLine()).length() != 0) which runs through all the numbers but also stops working. I think it's cause System.in is looking for input and not returning anything to judge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement break for an empty line, get the line trim and check if empty.

Your way:

```
    while ((line = read.readLine()) != null){
        if(line.trim().equals("")){
            break;
        }
        hold = hold.concat(line);
    }
```

Using Scanner instead:

```
...
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        if(line.trim().equals("")){
            break;
        }
        hold = hold.concat(line);
...
```

Comment: It can't resolve in. is that supposed to be System.in?

Comment: Both of those work perfectly. Do you suggest using Scanner or BufferedReader generally or does it just dependent on the situation?

Comment: Using `Scanner` is better in this situation, `scanner` has some built in functionalities like `hasNextLine()` `nextInt` ... and so on. `BufferedReader` does have its own use cases and can be used alongwith Scanner as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader

Answer (score 6):

`System.in` reads until the stream reaches its end. If you use the Java program in *interactive* mode, this means the string normally doesn't end, unless the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or a key combination that is recognized by the terminal operator that will close the input stream.

You can do a few things:

- use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to end the terminal input
- Use a file as input feed (`java -jar program.jar < inputfile`). In that case the stream will terminate after the end of the file
- implement a *stop code*:

  ```
  while ((line = read.readLine()) != null){
      if(line.equals("stop")) {
          break;
      }
      hold = hold.concat(line);
  }
  ```

  Here the java program will end when you enter `stop` for a certain line.

Comment: Is there a way to have it stop if there's nothing left being input. like ((line = ...) != "") or something?

Answer (score 0):

Assignment inside a condition is ok in this case, as the assignment is surrounded by an extra pair of parentheses – the comparison is obviously != null, there is no chance that we wanted to type *line == reader.readLine()*.

However, a for loop might actually be more elegant here:

```html
for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
    doSomething(line);
}
```

Alternatively, we could do this which also restricts the scope of line as with the for-loop, and additionally eliminates unnecessary repetition:
**Note:** This method doesn't mutate any variables

```html
while (true) {
    final String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) break;

    doSomething(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isEmpty() function of string class to check if string is empty.

```
while ((line = read.readLine()) != null&&!line.isEmpty())
{
     hold = hold.concat(line);
}

System.out.print(hold);
```