# How BufferedReader works in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I want to know how the BufferedReader works? Why InputStreamReader is used with it? How it differs from the Scanner class which is also used to take user input?
Which among the two is better?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: If you want to know; why don't you try to find out? Like, you yourself,  by doing some prior research before coming here and asking other people to spent their time **teaching** you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it neither poses a specific programming question, nor demonstrates a basic level of effort.

Answer (score 5):

The main differences are

1. Scanner is used for parsing tokens from the contents of the stream
   while BufferedReader just reads the stream and does not do any
   special parsing.
   In fact you can pass a BufferedReader to a scanner as the source of
   characters to parse.
2. Another difference is the size of the buffer. Scanner has a much
   smaller buffer than the BufferedReader (1024 chars as opposed to
   8192 chars). Although this may sound like quite a gap, the Scanner's
   buffer is *more* than enough for most tasks.
3. Scanner also **hides** IOExceptions while BufferedReader throws them
   immediately, this presents advantages and disadvantages.
4. Lastly, BufferedReader is synchronous while Scanner is not. Use
   BufferedReader if you're working with multiple threads.

You could have found this very easily by googling it.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader) a good link.

Answer (score 3):

From javadoc of `BufferedReader`

*Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.*

From javadoc of `Scanner`

*A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions. A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.*

Basically `BufferedReader` reads efficiently chars.

`Scanner` split chars sequences in tokens (similar to words) and permit to access to some basic types(or classes) (like `int, long, byte, double, String`...). It is an helper class to parse input, not to buffer it.