# How to search a String Backup = True in a text file

Tags: java

There is a space between before and after = ...

( Backup = True )------ is a String to search(Even space is there between =)

```
File file = new File(
                "D:\\Users\\kbaswa\\Desktop\\New folder\\MAINTENANCE-20150708.log.txt");

        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // now read the file line by line...
        int lineNum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.next();
            lineNum++;
            String name="Backup = True";
            if (line.contains(name)) {
                System.out.println("I found "+name+ " in file " +file.getName());
                   break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("I didnt found it");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Use `nextLine()` rather than `next()`.

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner.next()` returns the next complete token, so it will be returning something like `Backup`, then `=` next time round the loop, then `true` next time.

Use `Scanner.nextLine()` to get the entire line in one go.

Answer (score 0):

`scanner.nextLine()` would solve your problem.
If you want to stick with `scanner.next()` you can define a delimiter: `scanner.useDelimiter("\n")` this reads the file until it hits the delimiter and starts the next loop from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file line-by-line and search for your string in every line. The code should look something like:

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
   if(lineFromFile.contains(inputString)) { 
       // a match!
       System.out.println("Found " +inputString+ " in file ");
       break;
   }
}
```

Now to decide between `Scanner` or a `BufferedReader` to read the file, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader). Also check this [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44021/fast-way-of-searching-for-a-string-in-a-text-file) for fast way of searching a string in file. Also keep in mind to close scanner once you are done.