# Replace Scanner with BufferedReader

Tags: java

I have one stupid question: how could I replace Scanner with BufferedReader in this method:

```
public Coordinates getShot() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x,y;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter Х: ");
        x = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter Y: ");
        y = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.printf("\nYou entered: [%d,%d]\n", x, y);
        if(!Coordinates.checkCoordinates(x, y))
            System.out.println("Error");
    } while(!Coordinates.checkCoordinates(x ,y));
    Coordinates shot = new Coordinates(x, y);
    return shot;
}
```

Comment: What useful methods did you find while searching the javadoc of the `BufferedReader` class? How do these compare with `nextLine` and other features of `Scanner`?

Answer (score 0):

See [Scanner vs. BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader?rq=1)

> Scanner is used for parsing tokens from the contents of the stream while BufferedReader just reads the stream and does not do any special parsing.
>
> In fact you can pass a BufferedReader to a scanner as the source of characters to parse.

It would be possible, but would have no interest to use a BufferedReader here:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
//....
int x,y;
System.out.print("Enter Х: ");
x = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
System.out.print("Enter Y: ");
y = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
System.out.printf("\nYou entered: [%d,%d]\n", x, y);
```

Comment: Actually I need a BR to wrap this code into try/catch. But I don't know how to do it correctly.