# why does taking input through bufferedreader throw a garbage value in my system?

Tags: java, input

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int a = inp.read();
    System.out.println(a);
    inp.close();
}
```

Console:

`10` but it outputs `49` as result

Comment: `read` reads one character only, and returns its Unicode value. The char read is '1' and its unicode is 49

Comment: It prints the value you would expect if you read the documentation for `Reader.read()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it as :

```
Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

`BufferedReader#read` reads single character[0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff)] from the stream, so it is not possible to read single integer from stream.

An `InputStreamReader` needs to be specified in the constructor for the `BufferedReader`. The `InputStreamReader` turns the byte streams to character streams

You can check [scanner-vs-bufferedreader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader)

Answer (score 0):

Because 49 is the Unicode value for the character `'1'`. [`read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--) returns a single character (as an `int`, so it can use -1 to signal end-of-stream).

Options:

- If you want to read an entire line of text, use [`readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) to read a string.
- If you want to output the character you read, after checking that it's not -1 (which means you've reached the end of the stream), cast it to `char`:

  ```
  if (a != -1) {
      char ch = (char)a;
      System.out.println(ch); // will output 1
  }
  ```

  If you want to read all the characters, you'll need a loop.
- If you want to read an integer, you may want [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: To make it clear, when use read(), input 10 => only 1 is read =>

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String a = inp.readLine();
    System.out.println(a);
    inp.close();
```

read reads only single character and returns ascii value. Use readLine() to read full line and convert it into Integer.

Comment: Not ASCII, UTF-16: [The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read--). Many, many mentions of ASCII are erroneous.