# How can I parse lines of data from file to populate objects for each?

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

I have a text file with the list inside, every line has data that I need insert in the new objects. So data looks like `somename=3000`  or another type with the slash `data another type = 6000`.

I have particular class "Item" that has `String` and `int` variable. Data need to be inserted into them. Every new object has to be added to the `ArrayList<Item>`.

```
// Calculate the lines for next for each loop
int lineCount = 0;
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    lineCount++;
    sc.nextLine();
}

for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
    // creating the object
    Item item = new Item();
    // add item object to items ArrayList
    items.add(item);

    // add line to String variable lineToString,
    while (scaner.hasNextLine()) {
        String lineToString = scaner.nextLine();
        sc.nextLine();
    }
```

So, I figured out that to do this, I need to

- copy the whole line and put into some string variable;
- split it for integer and string variable;
- insert string parts to the String variable and numbers to the int variable in particular object that was created in iteration time of "for loop".
- add the object with a data inside to the ArrayList.

I used `Scanner` to read a text file. When I try to insert the `scaner.nextLine` to the `String` it's doesn't work; I mean it's executing but variable String `lineToString` doesn't have the line from a text file.

Could somebody help with an idea of how better to proceed with this problem? Maybe there is some simpler way to insert the 2 different type of data from the text file line in the object and put it into the `ArrayList`? Every line in the text file has different data and has to be in different objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention clearly the line format from the text file. I assume so far you have text file in which each line is like

```
someone=140000
```

And you are trying to read those lines of the text and parse each of them to an object of `Item` which contains a `String` property (I assume you name it `name`) and an `int` property (I assume you name it `number`)

If this is it, you fisrt need to read your text file line by line and process it further. There are several ways to read a text file line by line.

### BufferReader

This is a very common and so far most appropriate way to read a text file in consider of performance.

```
List<Item> particulatItems = new ArrayList<>();

// using try-with-resource that will help closing BufferedReader by own
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       particularItems.add(processLine(line));
    }
}
```

### Scanner

You could use `Scanner` too.

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
     while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        particularItems.add(processLine(line));
     }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should extract the line processing logic to a independent function. This is good practice of clean coding.

```
public static Item processLine(Strinng line) {
     String[] tokens = line.split("=");
     Item item = new Item(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
}
```

Assuming you have that *particular object* defined as `Item` and you are populating a `List` of this type

```
 public class Item {
    String name;
    int number;

    public Item(String name, String numtxt) {
       this.name = name;
       this.number = Integer.parseInt(numtxt);
    }

   // setter getter
 }
```

**More reading:**

1. [How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)
2. [Different ways of Reading a text file in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/)
3. [Difference between Scanner vs BufferReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader)
4. [Try-with-resources in Java 7](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have already scanned full file in below code snippet:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    lineCount++;
    sc.nextLine();
}
```

After this, you are again iterating in for-loop but with same scanner, which has read last line
So the following may return false:

```
while (scaner.hasNextLine())
```

I it may never enter while loop

You should reset scanner before iterating lines again .. or may be use something else than scanner to count lines

Comment: Thank you for an explanation, it was exactly like you said, never entered the while loop. I didn't know why, didn't know that by using that code, you scanning whole file! You really helped bro!

Comment: Glad to know if my answer really helped

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @Ashish Mishra mentioned, you are doing the second while loop in a for loop, why? Isn't one loop sufficient?

```
    int lineCount = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        lineCount++;
        String lineToString = sc.nextLine();
        Item item = new Item();
        //convert lineToString to item
        items.add(item);
    }
```

Comment: @Shafin Mahmud posted the perfect solution for this problem. Thanks for the feedback!