# What is the point of using user defined Scanner class to read data in Java?

Tags: java, user-defined

This code is from a competition, it works just fine if I use the built-in Scanner class to read data. But here, in this original solution, they defined a custom class MyScanner to read data? Why is that? Does it has anything to do with the execution time or is there some other purpose?
Any reasonable explanation or reference to related concept would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
class Main {
    final static int[] coins = {50, 25, 10, 5, 1};
    static int[][] memo;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        MyScanner sc = new MyScanner();
        Integer num = 7489 + 1;
        memo = new int[num+1][coins.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < num+1; i++) {
           Arrays.fill(memo[i], -1);
        }
        while ((num = sc.nextInt()) != null) {
            int r = change(num, 0);
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }

    private static int change(int num, int cInd) {
        if (num < 0){
            return 0;
        } else if (num == 0 || cInd == coins.length-1){
            return 1;
        } else if(memo[num][cInd] != -1) {
            return memo[num][cInd];
        }else {
            int result = change(num, cInd+1) + change(num-coins[cInd], cInd);
            return memo[num][cInd] = result;
        }
    }

    static class MyScanner {
        BufferedReader br;
        StringTokenizer st;
        public MyScanner() {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        }
        public String next() throws IOException {
            if (st == null || !st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null){
                    return null;
                }
                st = new StringTokenizer(line);
            }
            return st.nextToken();
        }
        public Integer nextInt() throws IOException {
            String next = next();
            if (next != null) {
                return Integer.parseInt(next);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the competition prohibits the use of `java.util.Scanner`?

Comment: There is no excuse for this. `StringTokenizer` is (effectively) deprecated.

Comment: @Sweeper maybe... I just needed to if there's any difference in the effectiveness of the code.

Answer (score 4):

In programming competitions, one of the competition criteria can be how fast the competitor's code is able to process some text-based input file.
You will typically see this kind of thing (the `MyScanner` class) used because the developer thinks that gives him or her an "edge" in performance over using the standard classes.  People who are "into" competitive programming will develop their own personal toolkits ... to improve their edge.

It is not clear whether this class will *really* perform better *in general*, or whether the contribution to the overall performance will be significant.  One would need to:

1. write some general benchmarks, and
2. profile the solution to the competition problem.

But in one sense, it doesn't matter.  What really counts is that the person who uses this kind of code *believes* it is better.  Either way, it does what they think is necessary.  The ends justifies the means.

---

On the other hand, if you were to do this kind of thing in *production* code, you would probably be doing your project / employer a disservice:

1. It is unlikely that this kind of thing will help in real life applications.
2. You would be adding a technical burden in the form of unnecessary / possibly flakey code for your colleagues / successors to maintain.

You should only resort to this kind of thing if your profiling *of your application* shows that scanning is a significant performance bottleneck.

Even then, this kind of thing is most likely wrong:

```
        if (next != null) {
            return Integer.parseInt(next);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
```

since it is liable to be a source of unexpected NPEs.

Comment: If this is performance optimised code I would expect to see much less random boxing/unboxing - and that adds to your NPE point; with the amount of conversion from `int` to `Integer` and back I would imagine this code is very likely to throw NPEs from the most unexpected of places.

Comment: Well yes.  But my point is I think that the author >>thinks<< the code is more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

The right question to ask here is Scanner vs Buffered Reader as the solution is based on BufferedReader . You can read further here.

[Scanner vs. BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader)

I hope this will be helpful. Here are my 2 cents

- BufferedReader is synchronous while Scanner is not. BufferedReader
  should be used if we are working with multiple threads.
- BufferedReader has significantly larger buffer memory than Scanner.
- The Scanner has a little buffer (1KB char buffer) as opposed to the
  BufferedReader (8KB byte buffer), but it's more than enough.
- BufferedReader is a bit faster as compared to scanner because scanner
  does parsing of input data and BufferedReader simply reads sequence
  of characters.

Comment: Thank you... guess I still have a long way to go.

Comment: Note that you can [create a `Scanner` with a `BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Readable)) reaping some of the benefits of `BufferedReader` - mainly speed. Also note that relying on `synchronized` within a `BufferedReader` to deal with concurrent IO is likely to result is horribly unperformant a likely incorrect IO.