# Java Equivalent to fscanf in C

Tags: java, c, file

Hi I i'm trying to do a line by line reading in of a file in Java. For example I'd like to be able to do something like

```
//c code
while( fscanf(ptr, "%s %s %s",string1,string2,string3) == 3)
     printf("%s %s %s",string1,string2,string3);
```

Where I scan in every line in the file individually and store it in a variable.

I have started out by making a file object and finding the file. However I haven't found a function to be able to read input.

Comment: [Just a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader)

Answer (score 3):

Use line oriented input, split the lines and print the contents. That is, read each `line`, check if you have three tokens (end if you don't) and print them. Like,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    if (tokens.length != 3) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n", tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]);
}
```

Change `System.in` to a `File` to read from a file.

Comment: Hi, what would I type where you wrote System.in? For example the file would be called file.txt

Comment: @User9123 `new File("file.txt")` - note that you are responsible for PATHing. So I would normally prefer something like `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "file.txt")`

Comment: for some reason, it is printing file.txt instead of of the lines in the file if I do the code up until the part with the tokens, any ideas why?

Comment: Yes. You forgot `new File`.

Comment: I see I have changed my scanner to a file, however now my nextLine() is not working

Comment: nevermind i fixed it with a try catch