# Reading an input using a bufferedReader compared to a Scanner (System.in)

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I read somewhere using **bufferedReader** is much faster than reading an input using a scanner. This would be beneficial when completing coding problems such as the ones available on DMOJ (which have time constraints). How would I read the input of int's and strings using a **bufferedReader** instead?

My current method:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);     //initializing scanner

String ____ = input.nextLine();              //reading a string input
int ____ = input.nextInt();                  //reading an int input
```

Comment: You will not get time advantage when reading from a keyboard input.

Comment: It's part of being "fast": `BufferedReader` does not do that. You would get an entire line, then blow it up with `split()`, then convert whatever parts need to be converted (`Integer.parseInt()` and the like). Being "buffered" has its charm, but you can do that with a stream too, wrap it into `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: @PM77-1 ,the program will be reading inputs from an online judge so I wouldn't be putting in the inputs myself.

Comment: @tevemadar I will look into BufferedInputStream's.

Comment: Performance wlll be dominated by the code of your solution to the problem, not by I/O of the input.

Comment: Refer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/2231399/2987755, for Q: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2231369/2987755

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter your name: ");

String name = reader.readLine();
System.out.println("Your name is: " + name);
```

You need to convert them manually based on the type of input you expect to receive.

**Ex:** For `int` you do `Integer.parseInt(inputValue)`

Comment: Casting won't do any good. The object is still a `String`. You can't cast it to just anything.

Comment: Sorry man. I meant converting but mentioned casting. My bad. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed my answer.