# Why to add a Empty String while adding an string with int?

Tags: java, arrays, string, concatenation

In the below when I wasn't adding the ""(Empty String), the output was in int, which is pretty abnormal because adding a String with an int always gives a string. But as soon as I added the Empty String thing, the code seemed to work fine. In both the cases,I was adding a string from the string array that I created earlier in the code.

```
import java.io.*;

public class TooLong{
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException{
        InputStreamReader n = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(n);
        byte i ;
        i=Byte.parseByte(input.readLine());
        String origWords[] = new String[i];
        for (int j=0;j<i;j++)   origWords[j]= input.readLine();
        for (int j=0;j<i;j++){

            int charLength = origWords[j].length(); 
            if (charLength < 11)    System.out.println(origWords[j]);
            else System.out.println(origWords[j].charAt(0) +""+ (charLength-2) + origWords[j].charAt(charLength-1) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `charAt(int index)` 

> Returns the char value at the specified index.

Comment: Can you show us some examples? I don't think I understand what you want to say.

Comment: `charAt()` return `char` (basically a number) the `+` is define as `number + number`, cause `char` only contains one char, once you introduce `String` (`""`) the `+` became concatenation of strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, you are trying to achieve “internationalization ⇒ i18n”

That is because `String.charAt(int)` returns `char`. Which will be treated as numerical when using `+`.
By using `+` with the empty String you force the compiler to convert everything to String

You can use `String.substring(0,1)` instead of the first `charAt` to force type String conversion

Comment: Got it, one more question on which I am not able to get a short answer is, Scannner or Buffered Reader?

Comment: :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader. My first google hit on “java Scanner or BufferedReader”

Answer (score 1):

The charAt() method of String returns the char. char is one of the primitive data types. char is a textual primitive, however, it also can do arithmetic operations like numerical primitives. The codes below are examples for it:

```
 `public static void main(String args[]){
            String st = "i am a string";
            char c = st.charAt(0);
            System.out.println(c);
            System.out.println(c+ st.charAt(2));
            System.out.println(c+ "" + st.charAt(2));
        }

`
```

The result of the above code will be:

```
 i
202
ia
```

Hope this example makes it clear.