# Java: How to sum all the values of one column based on the criteria in a second column using HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a CSV file that contains roughly 500,000 rows and 22 columns of flight data.  The 5th Column contains the tail number of each plane for each flight.  The 22nd column contains the distance traveled for each flight.  I'm attempting to sum the total distance traveled (column 22) for each tail number (column 5).

I created a `HashMap` containing all data named `map1`.  I created a 2nd `HashMap` named `planeMileages` to place each flight number and its total distance traveled into. I'm using a nested if statement go through each line of `map1` and see if the tail number is already contained in `planeMileages`.  If it is in `planeMileages`, then I want to add on to the `accumulatedMileages`for that key.  If it is not contained, I'd like to input the key along with it's first distance value.

The current code that I've written seems sound to me, but it is producing the wrong result, outputting the incorrect tail number.  Can you please take a look and let me know what I am overlooking in my main method? Thanks!

```
public class FlightData {

    HashMap<String,String[]>  dataMap;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            FlightData map1 = new FlightData();
            map1.dataMap = map1.createHashMap();

            HashMap<String, Integer> planeMileages = new HashMap();
            //Filling the Array with all tail numbers
            for (String[] value : map1.dataMap.values()) {

                if(planeMileages.containsKey(value[4])) {  
                    int accumulatedMileage = planeMileages.get(value[4]) + Integer.parseInt(value[21]);
                    planeMileages.remove(value[4]);
                    planeMileages.put(value[4], accumulatedMileage);
                } 
                else {
                    planeMileages.put(value[4],Integer.parseInt(value[21]));
                }
            }


            String maxKey = Collections.max(planeMileages.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();

            System.out.println(maxKey);


        }





       public HashMap<String,String[]> createHashMap() {
            File flightFile = new File("flights.csv");
            HashMap<String,String[]> flightsMap = new HashMap<String,String[]>();

            try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(flightFile);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {

                    String info = s.nextLine();
                    String [] piecesOfInfo = info.split(",");

                        String flightKey = piecesOfInfo[4] + "_" + piecesOfInfo[2] + "_" + piecesOfInfo[11]; //Setting the Key
                        String[] values = Arrays.copyOfRange(piecesOfInfo, 0, piecesOfInfo.length);

                        flightsMap.put(flightKey, values);


            }
            s.close();
            }


           catch (FileNotFoundException e)
           {
             System.out.println("Cannot open: " + flightFile);
           }

            return flightsMap;
        }
}
```

Please see a few lines of my CSV file below:

[image: Flights.csv]

```
DayofMonth  DayOfWeek   FlightDate  UniqueCarrier   TailNum OriginAirportID Origin  OriginStateName DestAirportID   Dest    DestStateName   DepTime DepDelay    WheelsOff   WheelsOn    ArrTime ArrDelay    Cancelled   CancellationCode    Diverted    AirTime Distance
3   1   10/3/2016   AA  N786AA  10721   BOS Massachusetts   12478   JFK New York    556 -4  623 703 709 -6  0       0   40  187
4   2   10/4/2016   AA  N794AA  10721   BOS Massachusetts   12478   JFK New York    554 -6  615 703 712 -3  0       0   48  187
1   6   10/1/2016   AA  N783AA  12478   JFK New York    12892   LAX California  823 -7  844 1104    1111    -30 0       0   320 2475
2   7   10/2/2016   AA  N798AA  12478   JFK New York    12892   LAX California  847 17  904 1131    1159    18  0       0   327 2475
3   1   10/3/2016   AA  N786AA  12478   JFK New York    12892   LAX California  825 -5  838 1109    1131    -10 0       0   331 2475
4   2   10/4/2016   AA  N794AA  12478   JFK New York    12892   LAX California  826 -4  848 1114    1132    -9  0       0   326 2475
```

Comment: Maps have a method `putIfAbsent()`, might help reduce some of the checking

Comment: If in this file you have flights that appear multiple times then `flightsMap.put(flightKey, values);` will remove the old data every time it is called. Also, what do you think this does `String[] values = Arrays.copyOfRange(piecesOfInfo, 0, piecesOfInfo.length);` ? I recommend you create more objects instead of keeping your data in string arrays.

Comment: I wonder why did you use `copyOfRange`, you can use directly `piecesOfInfo` as parameter in `put` function. Code is looking good. My suggestion is create a new csv file and fill with it, same tail number rows. And debug the for loop in `main` function. Let's see what will happen.

Comment: @HomelsWhereThePcls  that is a good suggestion.  I will try creating more objects

Comment: @FinDev please post your csv as text to copy

Comment: @Nonika is there a way for me to post my original file and not just a picture?

Comment: Use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Open with notepad and copy first few lines

Comment: @Nonika please see my update

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs thank you, I will try that website out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello can you check this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException {

    Map<String, String[]> map = createMap();
    Map<String, Long> planeMileages = map
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getValue()[4],
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.summarizingInt(value ->
                                    Integer.parseInt(value.getValue()[21])), IntSummaryStatistics::getSum
                    )
            ));
    String maxKey = planeMileages.entrySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)).get().getKey();
    System.out.println("max key: "+ maxKey);
}

public static Map<String, String[]> createMap() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader a = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("flights.csv"))) {
        return a.lines().map(s -> s.split(","))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(piecesOfInfo -> String.join("_", piecesOfInfo[4], piecesOfInfo[2], piecesOfInfo[11]), Function.identity()));
    }
}

public static Map<String, String[]> createMapLastDupWins() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader a = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("flights.csv"))) {
        return a.lines().map(s -> s.split(","))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(piecesOfInfo -> String.join("_", piecesOfInfo[4], piecesOfInfo[2], piecesOfInfo[11]), Function.identity(), (strings, strings2) -> {
                    //if this helps than data is duplicated
                    return strings2;
                }));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it failed with the following error messages.  I imported every package and there are no error messages or warnings in the code:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
.lang.String;@4f3f5b24

Comment: at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.HashMap.merge(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto

Comment: at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
 at FlightData.createMap(FlightData.java:120)
 at FlightData.main(FlightData.java:100)

Comment: I think the OP could benefit more from some pointers than just a block of code.

Comment: @FinDev can you post a few line of your csv?

Comment: @Nonika yes I will post in my original question

Comment: I know whats is the problem your key `piecesOfInfo[4] + "_" + piecesOfInfo[2] + "_" + piecesOfInfo[11]` is not unique

Comment: There are duplicate keys-s into the data do you want to just ignore?

Comment: @Nonika I want to sum the value for the key.  There should be repetitions in tail numbers because we want to find out how many miles that tail number traveled in the whole data sets.  Think of it like a ```SumIf``` formula in Excel.  There are 5000,000 rows of data but only 1,000 unique tail numbers

Comment: listen you have a method createHashMap() which is creating hashmap, some lines into your data has same key thus these lines are overwriting is it ok?

Comment: I understand that tailnum is duplicated but combination of TailNum+FlightDate+DepTime should be uniq. and its is duplicated also

Comment: @Nonika Good find, I definitely do not want to overide, I want a unique key for each line.  Maybe I'll just increment the key from to to 500,000

Comment: @FinDev are you sure that the data is ok. maybe the source is incorrect. if not you can generate some UUID for each line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209675/discussion-between-nonika-and-findev).

Comment: I have added new method for `creatingMap` `createMapLastDupWins` this way duplicates will be ignored and last one will win :) if this works than your keys is duplicated

Comment: @Nonika thank you so much for your help resolving the error.  I believe the overriding keys was in fact the driver of the variance

Answer (score 3):

Here is a bit more OOP way of doing it.

You extend the HashMap and add two new methods, one for adding flights and another for calculating total distance.
This way you are not constantly removing and adding back modified values into the HashMap.
You can expand on this to fit your needs.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FlightData flightData = getFlightDataFromFile();
        flightData.getDistanceTraveled("tail number");
    }

    public static FlightData getFlightDataFromFile() {
        File flightFile = new File("flights.csv");
        FlightData flightData= new FlightData();

        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(flightFile);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String info = s.nextLine();
                String[] piecesOfInfo = info.split(",");
                String tailNr= piecesOfInfo[4];
                Flight flight = new Flight(piecesOfInfo[6], piecesOfInfo[9], Integer.parseInt(piecesOfInfo[21]));
                flightData.addFlight(tailNr, flight);
            }
            s.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot open: " + flightFile);
        }
        return flightData;
    }
}

class FlightData extends HashMap<String,List<Flight>> {

    void addFlight(String tailNr, Flight flight) {
        computeIfAbsent(tailNr, flights -> new ArrayList<>()).add(flight);
    }

    int getDistanceTraveled(String tailNr) {
        int distance = 0;
        for (Flight f : get(tailNr)) distance+= f.distance;
        return distance;
    }

}

class Flight {
    String from;
    String to;
    int distance;

    public Flight(String from, String to, int distance) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: @HomelsWhereThePcls wow thank you so much for doing all this work, I will try implementing your solution now

Answer (score 1):

Try this , and if the miles are very huge change Integer to Long and then check

```
   HashMap<String, Integer> planeMileages = new HashMap<>();

    for (String [] value : flightsMap.values()) {

        if(planeMileages.containsKey(value[4])) {

            planeMileages.put(value[4], planeMileages.get(value[4])+Integer.valueOf(value[21]));

        } else {
            planeMileages.put(value[4], Integer.valueOf(value[21]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I really appreciate you coming up with this solution, I will try implementing it now

Comment: i guess generating key was the key ;) .